# Symfony form category - subcategory

Tags: forms, symfony, categories

I try to make a form with category and subcategory like the picture below :[image]

So, I made my form like that :

```
        ->add('souscategorie', EntityType::class, array(
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'class' => 'App:souscategorie',
                                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('souscategorie')
                                            ->leftJoin('souscategorie.categorie', 'categorie')
                                            ->addSelect('souscategorie')
                                            ->addSelect('categorie')
                                        ;
                                    },
                                    'expanded'=> true,
                                    'multiple'=> true,
                                    'choice_label' => function($sousCategorie){
                                        return $sousCategorie->getCategorie()->getNom()." - ".$sousCategorie->getNom();
                                    },
                                    'group_by' => function($sousCategorie, $key, $value){
                                        return $sousCategorie->getCategorie()->getNom();
                                    }))
```

The result show all categories and subcategories concatenate.

How to split categories and subcategories ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Can you please add your output/generated response to your question, since it's what the question is about?

Comment: Yes, I just want to try something before and if it works, I show the solution ;)

Comment: Do you want us to write your code for you? Because that's not what this site is for. Or what do you mean?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to do ! How to group subcategory by category like on the picture ? I don't know !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `tree` structure for your `categories` you can use [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)

Documentation for the bundle [is here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)

You would need to use `Tree` extension (nestedset variation).

Here is the example that shows [how to add categories](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example) to the project